# Pass an object method as SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack

Tags: objective-c, macos, argument-passing

Is there any way I could pass an object method instead of a function to a function wanting a `SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack` as its argument?

Here is how SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack is defined:

```
typedef void (*SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack)   (
                        SCNetworkReachabilityRef    target,
                        SCNetworkReachabilityFlags  flags,
                        void                *info
                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a block that sends the message, then have your C callback execute the block! :D

Basically, the C callback is going to act as glue code. Since an Objective-C method's IMP will never be of a type compatible with the callback, you are always going to need at least one level of indirection before you get to an Objective-C message dispatch. If you need to carry more state than just the object, a block may help you, but that C function stub isn't going anywhere.

Comment: Well I guess I might as well accept this, so it simply isn't possible without the C glue.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, you could write some C or C++ glue code and pass that function which would then call into your object method.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm doing now, but I think it would be cleaner if there was a way to directly pass the object method.